# NodeJS include functions

Tags: node.js

Lets say I have the following NodeJS file:

```
var https = require("https");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var options = {};
var serverPort = 8443;
var server = https.createServer(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var numUsers = 0;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile('/home/domain/index.php');
});                   

io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('user-login', function(data){
        ++numUsers;            
    }); 

    socket.on('new message', function (msg,room) {
        console.log(msg);
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", function() {
        --numUsers;
    });

});

server.listen(serverPort, function(){
    console.log("\n--------------------------------");
    console.log('Node HTTPs Server');
    console.log('Currently Listening on port %d',serverPort);
    console.log("--------------------------------");
});
```

Since I can't get [SNI to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45161376/nodejs-ssl-with-sni) on my server, I'll have to go the old fashioned way and write a script for each subdomain.  But what I'd like to do is have the functions inside of the `io.on('connection', function(socket) {}` area to be `included`.  So not included like a class or anything like that, but literally the code is just taken from another file and processed as if it were in that file already.  A lot like PHP does includes.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be to read code using `fs.readFile[Sync]` and pass it to `eval` inside `io.on('connection', function(socket) {})`

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('user-login', function(data){
        ++numUsers;            
    }); 

    socket.on('new message', function (msg,room) {
        console.log(msg);
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", function() {
        --numUsers;
    });
    // eval function loaded outside io.on('connection')
    eval(someFunctionBody);
    // or
    eval(fs.readFileSync('path/to/function/body.js'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use `require`?

**functions.js**

```
function myFunc() {
  console.log("I am a funky func");
}

module.exports = {
  myFunc,
  myOtherFunc,
};
```

**index.js**

```
var https = require("https");
var express = require("express");
// snip
var funcs = require('./functions');

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  // snip

  funcs.myFunc();
});
```